# Upgrading to Springboot 2.5.x crashes application start on Liberty server

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Spring Boot version (spring-boot-starter-parent): 2.5.1

Eclipse 2021

Liberty 20.x

After update to Spring Boot 2.5.1, I am getting following error when starting Liberty server to host my API

**[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://myhost.net:9089/myapi/**

**[ERROR   ] SRVE0285E: Exception caught while destroying context: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldInitialListener.contextDestroyed(WeldInitialListener.java:113)
at [internal classes]**

**[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0012I: The application myapi was not started.**

**[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://myhost.net:9089/myapi/**

I did Maven update and mvn clean install and all worked fine; however, starting liberty with my api is failing.  Above, the myapi gets deployed but then fails to start due to the error.  If I revert to Spring Boot 2.4.x or 2.3.x, it all works fine again.

Comment: On the face of it, It looks like a bug in Weld. Please share the complete stack trace of the NullPointerException and the version of Weld that your Liberty installation is using.

Comment: I cannot find any reference to Weld in my project, nor in Liberty  settings.xml file